# solc.compile() @0.5.0 is not working like 0.4 version

Tags: solidity, solc

I read the solc document and followed the instruction.
When I am using solc@0.4.24 version, compile command is working fine

```
solc.compile(smartContractPath, 1);
```

When I switched to solc@0.5.0 version, compile command throwing error

> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var Module;if(!Module)Module=(typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:null)||{};var moduleOverrides={};for(var key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof importScripts==="function";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=typeof process==="object"&&typeof require==="function"&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE){if(!Module["print"])Module["print"]=function print(x){process["stdout"].write(x+"\n")};if(!Module["printErr"])Module["printErr"]=function printErr(x){process["stderr"].write(x+"\n")};var nodeFS=require("fs");var nodePath=require("path");Module["read"]=function read(filename,binary){filename=nodePath"normalize";var ret=nodeFS"readFileSync";i
>
> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid callback specified.

In the [solc documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js) it is not mentioned about the changes in **compile** command.
Please tell how to use .compile function in solc@0.5.0 version.

Comment: Further down the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js#from-version-050) states: _Starting from version 0.5.0, compile, compileStandard and compileStandardWrapper all do the same thing - what compileStandardWrapper used to do._ There's some help how to use the new syntax here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49709550.

Comment: Yes, and below that it is also mentioned that compileStandard and compileStandardWrapper will be deprecated. Then only compile is remained there. In the error: it is giving error of invalid callback specified. May be in 0.5 callback is introduced in compile function but it is not mentioned in document

Comment: compile in v0.5 expect a json string and output a json string. The format of the input is in [solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/using-the-compiler.html#compiler-input-and-output-json-description). In the stackoverflow answer is the input equivalent to v0.4.xx behavior.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I also tried your method to compile and got the same error.
Finaly, I found a workable method in the official doc.

I tried it with solc@0.5.0. It's OK.

```
let contractSource = fs.readFileSync(contractPath, 'utf-8');
//console.log("contract content: \n" + contractSource);

let jsonContractSource = JSON.stringify({
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
      'Task': {
          content: contractSource,
       },
    },
    settings: { 
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': ['abi',"evm.bytecode"],   
             // here point out the output of the compiled result
            },
        },
    },
});

let solcResult = solc.compile(jsonContractSource);
```

You can see the output format of the compile in this link.

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/using-the-compiler.html#compiler-input-and-output-json-description