# solc/wrapper not working with reactjs

Tags: solidity, solc, react

My compile.js code:

```
var wrapper = require('solc/wrapper')
var solc = wrapper(window.Module)
const Compile = (code,name) => {
    return solc.compile(code, 1).contracts[':'+name];
};
export default Compile ;
```

I am getting below error:

```
./node_modules/solc/node_modules/require-from-string/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'module' in '/Users/amitchambial/work/contractdeployer/node_modules/solc/node_modules/require-from-string'
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: which solc version?

Comment: "solc": "^0.5.2",

Comment: See if this applies to your case https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63267/solc-compile-0-5-0-is-not-working-like-0-4-version